# At input() not working

Tags: angular

I am relearning a few things in Angular because I had to step away from it for a while because of other oblations. `@Input()` should be working but for some reason it is not and I am not getting any errors.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss']
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() isLoadings: boolean;
    @Input() parentData = 'Data from parent';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

Child component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    quote: string;
    isLoading: boolean;
    name: string;
    childMessage: string;
```

html:

```
<app-loader [isLoadings]="isLoading" [parentData]="childMessage">{{childMessage}}</app-loader>
```

the below works.

```
[isLoadings]="isLoading"
```

Why doesn't:

```
[parentData]="childMessage"
```

Comment: Who is the parent ? I think you mixed them up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**child:**   **LoaderComponent**

```
@Input() parentData:string;
```

**parent:** **HomeComponent**

```
childMessage ='Data from parent';
```

`@Input` in child component should receive the 'message' from the parent component, not the reverse.
`isLoading` works, because in both places it `= false` (default value for boolean type), and also the fact that you named both properties on the parent and the child maybe misleading you (but you can keep that way).

**Refactoring your example:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss']
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() isLoadings: boolean;
  @Input() parentData = '';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   quote: string;
   isLoading: boolean;
   name: string;
   childMessage ='Data from parent';
```

.....

Comment: That breaks it.

Comment: child is LoaderComponent , parent is HomeComponent. Have you put in this order?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45870800/angular-routing-uncaught-error

The issue never end. I am still learning