# Angular Routing uncaught error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following:

[image]

I am getting an error saying:

```
compiler.es5.js:1690 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("           <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
                    <li class="home"><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/home']">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="child"><a [routerLink]="['/child']">Child</a>"): ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.html@7:25
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("inline">
                    <li class="home"><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="child"><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/child']">Child</a></li>
                    <li class="parent"><a [routerLink]="['/parent']">Parent"): ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.html@8:26
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("</li>
                    <li class="child"><a [routerLink]="['/child']">Child</a></li>
                    <li class="parent"><a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/parent']">Parent</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

However I declared it in my app.modules.ts:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      BrowserModule,
      ChildModule,
      ParentModule,
      HomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In my HomeComponent.html I have the header:

```
<header id="header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-inline">
                    <li class="home"><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Login</a></li>
                    <li class="child"><a [routerLink]="['/child']">Child</a></li>
                    <li class="parent"><a [routerLink]="['/parent']">Parent</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

However it is saying it recognize the property.

I have uploaded the code to GitHub: [GitHub][2]

------------Update 1---------------

I updated `CommonModule.ts`

```
  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    // you don't need anything here since this module has no templates for Angular to parse!
    imports: [RouterModule],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class CommonModule { }
```

I then imported it into `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ChildModule,
      ParentModule,
      HomeModule,
      CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Errors:

[2]: https://github.com/drewjocham/Routing.gitERROR in

```
    ERROR in /Users/drew/Documents/OutputInput/Sample/node_modules/@angular/common/src/common_module.d.ts (11,15): Cannot find name 'RouterModule'.
ERROR in /Users/drew/Documents/OutputInput/Sample/node_modules/@angular/common/src/common_module.d.ts (13,9): Cannot find name 'RouterModule'.
```

Comment: can you please add the module in which you declare the HomeComponent?

Comment: was this issue solved?

Answer (score 4):

This is because `HomeComponent` is declared in a `Module` that doesnt import the `RouterModule`. `RouterLink` is a directive that belongs to it.

To solve this, you could add `RouterModule` into the imports array of the `HomeModule`.

Comment: If you (the OP) want to learn more about how modules work in Angular, check out this youtube video from ngConf:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o&t=1s

Comment: one of my favorites from ng-conf, recommended it to some of my office colleagues ;)

Answer (score 1):

To understand errors like this, it's good to know a bit about how Angular processes templates. The basic version is as follows:

1. Angular reads all the components, directives and pipes that imported modules export -- for instance when you import `BrowserModule` into your `AppModule`, all the components and directives of `CommonModule` will be read because `BrowserModule` exports `CommonModule`
2. Angular reads all the components, directives and pipes that are declared in the current module.

That lists makes up the context within which Angular operates when it scans your templates. This means that unless you declared a directive in your module or imported it from another module, when Angular comes across it in the module template, it won't recognize it and will give you an error such as:

> Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

So when you see that, you immediately know that in the context of this module, the `routerLink` directive was neither declared nor imported.

The fix is simple: Export `RouterModule` from your `CommonModule` so that routing directives (such as `routerLink`) will be available to all other modules. Alternatively, you could just import `RouterModule` directly.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [],
    // you don't need anything here since this module has no templates for Angular to parse!
    imports: [],
    exports: [
        HttpModule, CommonModule, RouterModule
    ]
})
export class CommonModule { }
```

Be careful not to use `RouterModule.forRoot()` since that is reserved for `AppModule`

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response. Please see update 1.

Comment: @Drew1208 first, rename your `CommonModule` to something else, because Angular already has its own. Maybe `CoreModule`.  Next, you changed your code in other ways. For instance, before your `CommonModule` was importing Angular's own but you took that out. Basically you made more changes than I suggested. All I said was to export `RouterModule` from your `CommonModule` (which itself should be renamed)